# How to destroy root Preact node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I want to destroy the root Preact DOM node. I initially render my component as follows:

```
import { h, render } from 'preact';
import App from "./components/App";

render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app");
```

How do I destroy `App`? Do I simply unmount the `#app` DOM node, or does Preact offer a method similar to React's [`unmountComponentAtNode()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode) method?

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: I work on preact.

Any rendered `preact` app can be easily destroyed by passing `null` to `render`:

```
render(null, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

We don't need any special functions to do that and have chosen to keep a small API surface area. The implementation for `unmountComponentAtNode` in `preact-compat` does literally just call `render` with `null`:

```js
// Excerpt from compat for Preact X
function unmountComponentAtNode(container) {
    if (container._prevVNode!=null) {
        render(null, container);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method like `unmountComponentAtNode()` without preact-compat.
A workaround is to use the third argument of the `render()` method to replace the component you want to unnmount by `''` or `null` like suggested here :
https://github.com/developit/preact/issues/53#issuecomment-184868295